# Find the maximun $n\in N^{+}$, such $x^n+y^n+z^n$ is divisible by $x+y+z$

Tags: number-theory

A prime number $p$ and integers $x,y,z$ with $0<x<y<z<p$ are given. Show that if the numbers $x^3,y^3,z^3$ give the same remainder when divided by $p$ , Find the maximun $n\in N^{+}$, such $x^n+y^n+z^n$ is divisible by $x+y+z$

when $n=2$ case be see [Poland 2003](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/p2070729#p2070729)

Comment: "give the same remainder when divided by p,.......?" Find the maximun etc. I think you have to edit adding something at the place of points

Comment: If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is divisible by $x+y+z$, should $x^{p+1} + y^{p+1} + z^{p+1}$, $x^{2p} + y^{2p} + z^{2p}$, $x^{3p-1} + y^{3p-1} + z^{3p-1}$, $\dots$, all divisible by $x+y+z$ by [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit your post.

Are you sure you don’t ask about the maximum $n$ such that all of the $x^m+y^m+z^m$ with $m> n$  are not divisible by $x+y+z$?

In your hyperlink,  [Poland 2003](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h375194p2070729), it is not question of maximum n but just for $n=2$.

See at the following example: $0<3<5<6<7$ and $3^3, 5^3, 6^3$ have the same residue, $-1$ modulo $7$.
In fact, $3^2+5^2+6^2= 5(3+5+6)$, this is true.

But you have also $3^4+5^4+6^4=143(3+5+6)$ so $n=2$ is not a maximum as required. And it is not proved in any way that $n=4$ is.