# $\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x+y+z}\in \mathbb N$ has infinitely many non-trivial solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468891/find-the-maximun-n-in-n-such-xnynzn-is-divisible-by-xyz) I find out the following problem in which it is not necessary the condition $x^3=y^3=z^3$ in some $\mathbb F_p$:

Prove there are infinitely many pairwise coprime triples of distinct natural numbers, $(x,y,z)$, such that:

$$\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x+y+z}\in \mathbb N$$

Comment: Let $x=0$. It becomes trivial.

Comment: Trivial. Fix $y = z = 0$ and let $x = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. Are you sure that is all there is to the question?

Comment: @ZerXLR: Natural and distinct integers, please

Comment: @Ataulfo You should have said so first :)

Comment: Please reedit your question to make it clear.

Comment: If you're discarding most of the solutions we've given you, why don't you just ask for all the solutions? We've repeatedly proved that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I don't know if the infinite set of non-trivial solutions I got has all the solutions.

Comment: Downvotes feel that these are really unfair and desire have been given purely mathematical intentions. My problem is interesting and the fact that it becomes difficult to respond immediately is not a reason to disqualify.

Comment: A reason to downvote/disqualify your question is that you were completely unclear with your use of the term 'non-trivial'. My thoughts as to why you didn't clear this up immediately when asked is that you didn't even think about what you meant by that. I hope my edit shows that.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Once, an engineer in Venezuela claims to have demonstrated FLT (it was happen before Wiles and Company).He said that if there was a solution (x, y, z) also had infinite solutions (kx, ky, kz) then Theorem Faltings apply to complete his proof. Stupidity was not so much the reasoning but in believing that a man like Faltings had missed this observation when his great magnificent proof of Mordell's Conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many pairwise coprime solutions $x,y,z$.

$(x,y,z)=(m,n,m+n)$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $m$ even.

Motivation: $$x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y+z)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx\right)+3xyz$$

Therefore:

$$x+y+z\mid x^3+y^3+z^3\iff x+y+z\mid 3xyz$$

If $(x,y,z)=(m,n,m+n)$, then $$\iff 2(m+n)\mid 3mn(m+n)\iff 2\mid mn$$

Since you want pairwise coprime solutions, we can let $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Completely different of mine. But this works.  For interest of other users I'll give my answer below.Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=y=z$ then:

$$
\frac {x^3+y^3+z^2}{x+y+z}=\frac {3x^3}{3x}=x^2\in \Bbb N, \forall x\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}
$$

Furthermore, let $z=0,y=1$, then:

$$
\frac {x^3+y^3+z^2}{x+y+z}=\frac {x^3+1}{x+1}=x^2-x+1\in\Bbb N, \forall x\in\Bbb N-\{1\}
$$

Comment: See the edit please. I mean non trivial solutions.

Comment: Done :~). ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

I want to solve a more general question. I give here an infinite family of solutions without details for the case $n=3$, just for complement the nice answer of @user236182.

$$(x,y,z)=(t^2-2t,\space2t-3,\space t^2-3t+3)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution then so is $(px, py, pz)$ for any integer $p$. So even if $x$, $y$, and $z$ have to be distinct there are infinitely many solutions (once you find the first one).

Comment: Without common factors,please. Non trivial infinitely many

Comment: @Ataulfo It's your responsibility as the person asking the question to define "non-trivial": the term can mean many things in different contexts, so just calling them non-trivial isn't enough.

Comment: I think it is a question of common sense to see what is trivial. For example $x=y=z$ or when $xyz=0$ or $(kx,ky,kz)$. The given example in my edition is obviously non-trivial.